# Looking to edit a woocommerce action - can't figure out where the action is actually composed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action

I'm trying to add the product search bar function `get_product_search_form();` to the archive sorting action for Woocommerce, so it nicely fits in without being in between the woocommerce-message pop-up and the sorting inputs. I've figured out where the actions are created (includes/wc-product-functions.php), and the lines are as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
```

So how do I actually edit the actions? Is it even possible to cleanly edit these? I'd like the add the function in either of these actions, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Nevermind. Had been searching for the wrong function for hours. 

orderby.php

Comment: Would be great if you can post your results as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Pull file from plugins:
/woocommerce/includes/loop/orderby.php

Place in your theme:
/woocommerce/loop/orderby.php